# Как выбрать последнее вхождение, удовлетворяющее запросу?

Tags: mysql, sql

подскажите пожалуйста, как решить следующую проблему.
Есть вот такой запрос:

```
UPDATE sales AS s
JOIN payments_parts pp ON pp.FK_sale = s.ID
JOIN payments pay ON pp.FK_payment = pay.id 
SET s.plan_payment_date = pay.payment_date 
WHERE s.ID = pp.FK_sale
  AND pay.ID = pp.FK_payment;
```

Проблема в том, что в таблице payments может быть несколько строк, удовлетворяющих запросу и в результат попадает первая. Мне нужно, чтобы попадала последняя, а в идеале по максимальному значению поля pay.payment_date.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать.
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE sales AS s
JOIN payments_parts pp ON pp.FK_sale = s.ID
JOIN ( SELECT id, MAX(payment_date) payment_date 
       FROM payments 
       GROUP BY id) pay ON pp.FK_payment = pay.id 
SET s.plan_payment_date = pay.payment_date;
```

**UPDATE**

> Там (в `payments_parts`) тоже может быть не одна запись.

```
UPDATE sales AS s
JOIN ( SELECT pp.FK_sale, MAX(pay.payment_date) payment_date 
       FROM payments_parts pp
       JOIN payments pay ON pp.FK_payment = pay.id
       GROUP BY pp.FK_sale) p ON p.FK_sale = s.ID
SET s.plan_payment_date = p.payment_date;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Странно, не помогло. Может быть MAX() для типа DATE как-то не так срабатывает?

Comment: @lost А в `payments_parts` точно имеется **только одна** запись, соответствующая записи в `sales`?

Comment: ох блин, правда, совсем забыл. Там тоже может быть не одна запись. Но там нужно выбрать просто по максимальному id. Не подскажете, как?

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Большое спасибо. помогло. Я правда не до конца понял как именно работает запрос, буду разбираться :). Еще раз большое спасибо за помощь.